# Replace Specified Color with Transparency in CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to replace a specified color with transparency in CSS?

We have an image with white (255,255,255) parts. I am trying to use the **rgba** function to convert the white parts to transparency, but it's not working.

This image lies on top of another image, a blue background. The white shows through.

```
.logo {
background: url("../images/MasterLogo_resized.png") no-repeat scroll center 
    top rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.logo {
background: url("../images/MasterLogo_resized.png") no-repeat scroll center 
     top rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: CSS does not work that way...

Comment: No, I don't think so. You'd have to use a graphics program to map the alpha channel to transparency in the white areas of the image, and then save it in a format that supports transparency, such as `png`.

Comment: Are you trying to change the transparency of a color *within* the actual PNG? Or are you trying to change the transparency of a color *behind* the png?

Comment: Transparency within the actual image. Thanks, looks like CSS can't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the properties of a PNG using css.

But, if your PNG is simple enough to be converted to an SVG (using a graphics program), you could use CSS to manipulate transparency and colors:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/manipulating-svg-icons-with-simple-css--webdesign-15694